# Can't seem to get clean assets in my Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I've run the following and I'm still getting the old asset stylesheet. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
rake tmp:clear && rake assets:precompile
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run `rake assets:clobber`.

```
$ rake -T | grep clobber
rake assets:clobber  # Remove compiled assets
```

Comment: I ran this and then `rake assets:precompile` but it didn't load all my assets. Some JS files are missing.

Comment: nvm its all in the application js file.